# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:TemplateProcessingException in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I define every thing properly , But I do not know why I am getting
> issue with first name in variable in my thymeleaf page, I am getting
> below issue when I click on my signup button .

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "firstName" (template: "PlayerRegistration" - line 31, col 76)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SelectionVariableExpression.executeSelectionVariableExpression(SelectionVariableExpression.java:158) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:92) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.processDefaultAttribute(StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.java:165) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.process(StandardDefaultAttributesTagProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

> Here is my registration Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link  th:href="@{/../css/playerReg.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>PlayerRegistration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/nav :: navbar">


</div>

<section class="vh-100 bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/search-box/img4.webp');">
    <div class="mask d-flex align-items-center h-100 gradient-custom-3">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
                    <div class="card" style="border-radius: 15px;">
                        <div class="card-body p-5">
                            <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center mb-5">Create an account</h2>

                            <form th:action="@{/newPlayer}" method="post" th:object="${player}">

                                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                    <input type="text" id="fnTxt" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <label class="form-label" for="fnTxt"  th:field="*{firstName}">First Name</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                    <input type="text" id="phNTxt" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phNTxt"th:field="*{phoneNumber}">Phone Number</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                    <input type="email" id="emTxt" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <label class="form-label" for="emTxt"th:field="*{email}">Your Email</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                    <input type="password" id="pwTxt" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                    <label class="form-label" for="pwTxt"th:field="*{password}">Password</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                                    <input
                                            class="form-check-input me-2"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value=""
                                            id="form2Example3cg"
                                    />
                                    <label class="form-check-label" th:for="form2Example3g">
                                        I agree all statements in <a th:href="@{/term}" class="text-body"><u>Terms of service</u></a>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Register" />
                                </div>

                                <p class="text-center text-muted mt-5 mb-0">Have already an account? <a href="#!" class="fw-bold text-body"><u>Login here</u></a></p>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

> Here is my registration page controller end point

```
 @PostMapping("/newPlayer")
    fun registerPlayer(player: Player,modelAndView: ModelAndView):ModelAndView{
        modelAndView.addObject("player",player)
        playerService.newPlayer(player)
        modelAndView.viewName = "PlayerRegistration"
        return modelAndView
    }
```

> Here is my player service

```
package com.nilmani.herokudemoapplication.service

import com.nilmani.herokudemoapplication.entity.Player
import com.nilmani.herokudemoapplication.repository.PlayerRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.util.*

@Service
class PlayerService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var playerRepo:PlayerRepository

    fun newPlayer(player:Player):Player{
        if (player.id == null){
            return playerRepo.save(player)
        }else{
            val playerOptional:Optional<Player> = playerRepo.findById(player.id)
            if (playerOptional != null){
                val player1:Player = playerOptional.get()
                player1.firstName = player.firstName
                player1.phoneNumber = player.phoneNumber
                player1.email = player.email
                player1.password = player.password
                 playerRepo.save(player1)
                return player1
            }else{
                 playerRepo.save(player)
                return player
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> player Entity class

```
package com.nilmani.herokudemoapplication.entity

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.Email
import javax.validation.constraints.Max
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty

@Entity
data class Player (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    @NotEmpty(message = "please provide a name")
    var firstName:String="",
    @NotEmpty(message = "phone number contain only digit")
    @Max(11)
    var phoneNumber:Long=-1,
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email
    var email:String="",
    var password:String="",
        )
```

> Here is my get function @GetMapping("/player")

fun getRegistration():String{
return "PlayerRegistration"
}

> 

> I am using intelij ultimate 2021.1 version as code editor, and mac as
> operating system.

Comment: Can you add the code of the `@GetMapping` in your controller ?